# Why is Nginx reverse proxy to Bokeh server not working?

Tags: python, nginx, reverse-proxy, web-application

I am trying to set up Nginx reverse proxy to a web app being served by Python bokeh server as instructed here:

https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

For testing I am using a simple myapp.py from the same link. I use bokeh serve myapp.py --port 5100 to start the app.

My Nginx server is up and running. I have modified the Nginx setup to allow reverse proxy to port 5100 like so:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name _;

access_log  /tmp/bokeh.access.log;
error_log   /tmp/bokeh.error.log debug;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

}

However when I visit http://localhost, I get sent to localhost/myapp and a Page 404 error. The app is still running fine on localhost:5100/myapp.

What am I doing wrong? Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set up NGINX to reverse proxy requests to port 5006 by specifying the the `--prefix` option in the `bokeh serve` command.

Bokeh serve command example:

```
bokeh serve myapp.py --port=5006 --prefix=/apps
```

NGINX configuration:

```
location /apps {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5006;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

You should be able to access your Bokeh application using the URL: `http://localhost/apps/myapp`.